# How to reset a model on a button click in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app in `AngularJS`. There I have a table and it has 5 columns.
first three columns contain text fields where user can fill the data and next two columns contain a submit and reset button.
On the press event of the reset button I want to reset all the three models associated with the text fields.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Change the reset function to use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
$scope.reset = function () {
    $scope.datas = angular.copy($scope.initial);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your object is like

```
$scope.data = { column1:"asas", column2:"asas", column3:"asadas" };
```

You can don it in 2 way

1.`<button ng-click="data = {};"></button>`

2.`<button ng-click="reset();"></button>`

```
 $scope.reset = function(){
     delete $scope.data;
 }
```